# could not read setting.xml file for maven

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, maven

> I had downloaded my maven plugin from eclipse market place and now i
>   need to set setting.xml file in window-preference-maven-user settings
>   block,but i am unable to find setting.xml file, i had also looked in
>   .m2 directory but their is only repository directory is their. so
>   please tell where should i look to get setting.xml. please also tell
>   me what is the term proxy in setting.xml file, i am new to maven so i
>   don't know much about this.  Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the maven installation from [here](http://www-eu.apache.org/dist/maven/maven-3/3.5.0/binaries/apache-maven-3.5.0-bin.zip). Extract the zip and there will be settings.xml.

Proxy are used so that maven use that information to download artifacts in corporate environments.

Comment: It's not intended that you modify the `settings.xml` file that comes in the `conf` directory of a maven installation. It should be copied into the `.m2` directory in your home directory. This preserves it between maven upgrades.

Answer (score 2):

There are two locations where a settings.xml file may live:

1. The Maven install: ${maven.home}/conf/settings.xml
2. A user’s install: ${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml

See, [this](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html) for detail overview.

Also , maven use maven use proxy setting to download artifacts in corporate environment. Like  if you are running maven behind firewall in corporate, 
Maven need to be configured with proxy settings, See [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html) for detail.